# Why my ASP.NET text fields keep their value on Postback when a prior Javascript event has removed its value

Tags: asp.net, ajax, postback

I have a basic form with some ASP.NET textbox fields laid out and I also have created a control extender which after a change event on a seperate textbox occurs it sets a certain set of textboxes values to blank.

The form I have is a user control which exposes public properties to retrieve the values of the TextBoxs. When the form is submitted and I access the properties, the original values when the page was loaded are coming back instead of the blank or null value. Can someone explain to me why this is happening.

I have a page with the control on it, that control has the textboxs and the properties to expose the textbox values. After client events the populated textboxes are set to blanks. When I submit the form (submit button is on the control, but an event is exposed that I wire up on the parent form) I try to access the controls properties but they contain the original values.

I think this has something to do with the state bag but am not sure.

Any help would be great.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change values using ajax/jquery or anything client side the new values don't interact with the ViewState. Therefore when the page reloads the original values are restored from the ViewState wiping out anything that has happen via ajax.

This is a fault/feature of the asp.net postback model. I believe it is why the MVC framework has become popular - it doesn't have postbacks or viewstate at all so plays a lot nicer with AJAX.

I have got AJAX to work and persist with postbacks but it's a pain. I did the following

1. Have a hidden field at that we use to store the client state
2. For each client change store the change in the hidden field. Because the change will be complex - code up the change in JSON. For instance a string with value/ClientID pairs.
3. When the page post back - hook in a javascript function to read the state from the hidden field. Parse the JSON to an object and use custom code to reset the field values.

It's what I did - there might well be a better answer/work around.

In short - postbacks destroy AJAX

Comment: This is not entirely correct, I think.  Using an update panel will keep your state.

Comment: Good point - I'm talking about AJAX as mediated through JQuery or the XMLHttpRequest object generally. Update panels will play well with postbacks. TBH I don't think of them as AJAX though I know they are. And I've seen them abused so often I prefer not to think of them at all sometimes

Comment: Setting text fields with value from an AJAX callback will also be updated when posted to the server though...  regardless of how it is done.

Comment: thanks for the feedback guys. I guess I will have to look at other options.

Comment: I'll give you the check if no more answers filter in.

Comment: I'm starting to think you are right. When i did this is was maintaining the selected index of a dropdown. I that case the client value is definitely lost. But the text box will persist like you say. Could it be overwritten by the ViewState. I'm going to delete this post in a minute - i think it's wrong. Just interested in your response

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have your textboxes that you change set to disabled on the server side.  In this case, the values will not be posted back to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Hey its not possible to clear your text box value from javascript.. coz its load again from viewstate...

I m not sure but try this

```
 EnableViewState  = false
```

it may help you..